# Better version of Compare Extension for Linq

Tags: performance, linq

I need to get differences between two IEnumerable. I wrote extension method for it. But as you can see, it has performance penalties. Anyone can write better version of it?

**EDIT**

**After first response, I understand that I could not explain well. I'm visiting both arrays three times. This is performance penalty. It must be a single shot.**

PS: Both is optional :)

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
 public static ComparisonResult<T> Compare<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
    {
        // Looping three times is performance penalty!  
        var res = new ComparisonResult<T>
        {
            OnlySource = source.Except(target), 
            OnlyTarget = target.Except(source), 
            Both = source.Intersect(target)
        };
        return res;
    }
}

public class ComparisonResult<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> OnlySource { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> OnlyTarget { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Both { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependig on the use-case, this might be more efficient:

```
 public static ComparisonResult<T> Compare<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
    {
        var both = source.Intersect(target).ToArray();
        if (both.Any())
        {
            return new ComparisonResult<T>
            {
                OnlySource = source.Except(both),
                OnlyTarget = target.Except(both),
                Both = both
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new ComparisonResult<T>
            {
                OnlySource = source,
                OnlyTarget = target,
                Both = both
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Henric, real performance penalty is looping arrays three times. I've edited question.

Comment: Henrik, could you vote for reopen?, because this good question will die if it is not reopened.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an efficient full outer join.

Insert all items into a `Dictionary<TKey, Tuple<TLeft, TRight>>`. If a given key is not present, add it to the dictionary. If it is present, update the value. If the "left member" is set, this means that the item is present in the left source collection (you call it `source`). The opposite is true for the right member. You can do that using a single pass over both collections.

After that, you iterate over all values of this dictionary and output the respective items into one of three collections, or you just return it as an `IEnumerable<Tuple<TLeft, TRight>>` which saves the need for result collections.